# typescript with electron into vue.js context

Tags: typescript, electron

I would like to use typeorm library for manage data with entity. For that I wrote few files in typescript langage.

I use Webpack and Babel for compiling and packaging my source code for executing into electron app.

But when I launch my app I have error report on the compiling file typescript result.

This error not appear when I run webpack or babel transpiling but only on the exec code in electron.

I try to compil my typescript into two differents module definition (AMD, Commonjs) but the error seems to be the same.

**AMD context error :**

*tsconfig file :*

```
"target":"es5"
"module":"amd"
```

*public.js file (generated entity typeorm file in typescript source code)*

```
define(["require","exports","typeorm"],function(require,exports,typeorm_1)
```

*electron error :*

**define is not defined**

**Common.js context error :**

*tsconfig file :*

```
"target":"es5"
"module":"commonjs"
```

*public.js file (generated entity typeorm file in typescript source code)*

```
Object.defineProperty(exports,"_esModule",{value:true});
```

*Electron error :*

**Exports is not defined**

I try a lot of mix of parameters tsconfig but the error is the same with the compiled typescript file into electron app

I would to resolve issue but also understand why

Comment: You can use esm with `"target": "es2018"` and `"module": "esnext"` for electron depending on the version you use, but that's beside the point. Could you share your target option for webpack and if you set up the module config for babel ?

Comment: Your comment solve my error. Can you post a response with tsconfig example and add another key/value useful that "moduleResolution":"node" please.